# How to access an integer key inside a django template if the dict has a same string key?

Tags: django, django-templates

Suppose I've a dict like:

```
dic = {'1': 'string', 1 :'integer'}
```

When I pass it to a django template and try to access `dic.1` then it always returns `'string'`.

If I remove the key `'1'`, then `dic.1` returns `'integer'`.

I know I can use a custom tag for this, something like:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def get_key(value, arg):
    return value.get(arg, None)
```

Then `{{ dic|get_key:1 }}` works fine.

But, is there a way to directly access the integer/float keys without using a custom tag?

Comment: Why do you have a dict with 2 keys sharing the same name? That's a really bad idea to begin with. If I understand dict's correctly, then each time you make a key with a name already used, then you're overwriting the old data in the key

Comment: @Zamphatta No you don't understand dicts correctly, `'1'` and `1` are two different keys.

Comment: There is a ugliest way: {% for k, v in dic.items %}{% ifequal k '1' %}<!-- your html/js here -->{% endifequal %}{% endfor %}. But I would really avoid that. But reading that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970244/django-templates-value-of-dictionary-key-with-a-space-in-it) I don't think there is a better solution than template tags.

Comment: @Ricola3D Hmmm, I think I should start using jinja-templates which allows `dic[1]` syntax inside tags.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that? It sounds like bad idea. You are making your code much harder to read and maintain this way.

Comment: @Ricola3D I found out that your answer is (also) helpful when the dict's key is an int. It's non-trivial to access the dict's value from the template when the key is an int

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403681/dictionary-access-speed-comparison-with-integer-key-against-string-key) provided for the question on the topic of **Dictionary access speed comparison with integer key against string key**.  Python (CPython) will always first try to find the string-based key before attempting to find any alternative.

You *might* have a very good reason to mix similar string keys with integer keys, but I would recommend avoiding this technique or type-casting the integers to strings to eliminate the inability to directly reference the key values.