# Better to use dict of integer keys or a very long list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Basically, I need to make a lookup table with non-consecutive integer IDs. I'm wondering whether, in terms of lookup speed, I'm generally better off using a `dict` with integer keys anyway, or using a very long `list` with a lot of empty indices. It seems to me that a `list` might still be faster, as Python should know exactly where to look, but I'm wondering if there are any backend processes with the `dict` to compensate and whether the additional memory requirements for those empty `list` slots would negate the (probably) more easily traversed `list`'s speed gains. Are there any alternatives to `list`s and `dict`s that might be better suited to this?

I have seen this question, but it doesn't totally answer mine: [Dictionary access speed comparison with integer key against string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403681/dictionary-access-speed-comparison-with-integer-key-against-string-key)

ETA: I'm implementing lookup tables like this twice in my program. One instance sees a max id of 5,000 with 70-100 objects populated; the other has a max id of 750 with 20-30 populated.

Comment: Unless this is incredibly performance sensitive code, I wouldn't worry.  Use a `dict` - it's semantically much closer to what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To answer your question about `dict` vs `list` you'd have to give the *exact* information about the number of elements, the number of missing elements etc, so tha we could estimate exactly the memory usage of the two data structure and try to predict and/or check their performance.

In general a `dict` of `N` key-value pairs requires quite a bit more memory than a `list` with `N` values:

- The `dict` must keep track of the keys
- The `dict` is never more than 2/3 full. When this happens the memory allocated is doubled (this is required to have O(1) amortized time operations on the `dict`).

*However* there is an alternative to these data structure which should provide very good performance: [`blist`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/). The `blist` package provide an interface that matches that of `list`, only it is implemented using B-trees. It can efficiently handle sparse lists. Most operations take either `O(1)` or `O(log n)` time, so they are quite efficient.

For example you could first create a sparse `blist` doing:

```
from blist import blist

seq = blist([None])
seq *= 2**30    # create a 2**30 element blist. Instantaneous!
```

And then you can set only the indices that have a value:

```
for i, value in zip(indices, values):
    seq[i] = value
```

The full documentation is [here](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/).

Note that `blist` provides other efficient operations such as:

- Concatenating two `blist`s take `O(log n)` time
- Taking an `[i:j]` slice takes `O(log n)` time
- Inserting an element at a given index takes `O(log n)` operations
- Popping an element (from every position) takes `O(log n)` operations

---

Since you gave some numbers, here's how they compare to `dict`s:

```
>>> from blist import blist
>>> b = blist([None])
>>> b *= 5000
>>> for i in range(100):b[i] = i
... 
>>> b.__sizeof__()
2660
>>> d = dict()
>>> for i in range(100):d[i] = i
... 
>>> d.__sizeof__()
6216
>>> b = blist([None])
>>> b *= 750
>>> for i in range(30):b[i] = i
... 
>>> b.__sizeof__()
1580
>>> d = dict()
>>> for i in range(30):d[i] = i
... 
>>> d.__sizeof__()
1608
```

In both cases a `blist` takes less memory (in the first case it takes 1/3 of the memory of the equivalent `dict`). Note that the memory taken by a `blist` also depends on whether or not the indices are contiguous (contiguous is better). However even using random indices:

```
>>> b = blist([None])
>>> b *= 5000
>>> import random
>>> for i in range(100):b[random.randint(0, 4999)] = i
... 
>>> b.__sizeof__()
2916
```

It's still much better than the `dict`.

Even lookup times are better:

```
In [1]: from blist import blist
   ...: import random
   ...: 

In [2]: b = blist([None])

In [3]: b *= 5000

In [4]: for i in range(100):b[random.randint(0, 4999)] = i

In [5]: %timeit b[0]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 50.7 ns per loop

In [6]: d = dict()

In [7]: for i in range(100):d[random.randint(0, 4999)] = i

In [10]: %timeit d[1024]   # 1024 is an existing key in this dictionary
10000000 loops, best of 3: 70.7 ns per loop

In [11]: %timeit b[1024]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 50.7 ns per loop
```

Note that a `list` takes about `47 ns` to lookup an index on my machine, so `blist` is really really close to a `list` in terms of lookup performance on small lists as what you have.

Comment: So, the `blist` seems to be the response to @begueradj 's assertion that it's faster to access a `dict` than a `list`. How does the memory usage of a sparse `blist` compare to a `dict`? It seems like a 95% empty (from the numbers I added to the question) `blist` will still use more memory than a `dict` (although I don't understand how "_never more_ than 2/3 full" works; does a `dict` just occupy 1.5x the size of its data?), and even more memory if I begin by blindly making a large `blist` instead of calculating the max id first, or does `blist` collapse the empty indices somehow?

Comment: @Rus925 A sparse blist uses `O(log n)` memory where `n` would be the length of the actual list. This means that a `2**30` sparse blist (as in the example) occupies about `k * 30` bytes, where `k` is some constant. The memory used depends on how sparse is the list, and where the elements are (if they are clustered it's going to be more efficient). As the example shows it doesn't have to store all the actual elements (a `2**30` element list cannot be stored in RAM). Obviously if you know how many items you have you can use that number instead of a random big value.

Comment: @Rus925 I have updated my answer. AFAIK, from my tests a 95% empty blist takes *less* memory than a `dict` and is also faster to lookup.

Answer (score 3):

**Lists:**
 1. `append` and `pop` from the end of list are fast
 2. `insert` and `pop` from the beginning of a list are slow (there is a heavy shit operation behind these 2 functions)
 3. it is better to use [collection.degue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for the 2nd case.
**Dictionaries:**
 4. Access operations are faster compared to lists

**Looping through dictionaries and lists:**

1. Dictionaries use `iteritems()` method to retrieve at the same time the  key and its corresponding value.
2. Lists use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) for the same purpose.

   **Notes:**
3. If your question is just about looping speed, there is no tangible difference between [iteritems()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744568/why-do-you-have-to-call-iteritems-when-iterating-over-a-dictionary-in-python) and enumerate()
4. iteritems() is [removed](http://satyajit.ranjeev.in/2012/05/17/python-a-few-things-to-remember.html) in Python 3.x.
5. The [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) method is a heavy process to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no general answer to that question. It depends on the repartition of the integers id, the available memory and your performance requirements. The rules are :

- a list lookup is faster, because you do not have to compute the hash of the key.
- a dict may be more compact if the greatest value of key is large
- if your largest key is very large (about 2^30) you will waste a lot of memory and system will begin swapping which greatly degrades performances

Here is what could be a rule of thumb :

- if there are "few" empty values of if you know the largest key will be "reasonably" low (relative to the memory you accept to spend on that) => use a list
- if the following requirement is not verified and you do not have **strong** performance requirement => use a dict
- if none of the 2 preceding assumptions are true you will have to try some hash functions optimizations - I detail it below

The theory of the dict is an array for which the index is the result of a hash function applied to the key. Python algorythm is correctly optimized but it is a generalist one. If you know that you have special repartition, you could try to find a hash specially adapted to **your** repartition. You could find pointers to go further in the Wikipedia article on [Hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) or on the good old standard C library `hash`