# Updating an Object from a List in C#

Tags: c#, list, object

I have the following:

```
public class Animal
    public int currentPopulation 
    public string name

   public Animal(int currentPopulation, string name){
       this.currentPopulation = currentPopulation;
       this.name = name;
   }
```

In another class I have:

```
public class MainClass

   <List><Animal>animalList
   ...

   lion = newAnimal(100, "Lion");
   cat = newAnimal(20, "Cat");
   dog = newAnimal(40, "Dog")

   animalList.add(lion);
   animalList.add(cat);
   animalList.add(dog);
```

Every so often I have to fetch new data from a server and update the animal property, currentPopulation in the MainClass. Currently I'm doing this by the following:

```
public void UpdatePopulations(int lionPopulation, int catPopulation, int dogPopulation)

foreach(var item in animalList.where(n=>n.name=="Lion")){
   item.currentPopulation = lionPopulation;
}
... and the same for the cat and dog.
```

I feel like my solution is bulky and I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to update the objects from the list.

Comment: Rather than using a list, why not use a dictionary, where the key is the animal name?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts The code I have is simplified but essentially I have a slide show and a timer that shows information for each object in the list. So I thought it list might be easier to do it.

Comment: Do you want to update just an animal or all animals in the list? Don't you want to have a parameter for each name instead of hardcoding the `"Lion"`?

Comment: @kurakura88 i want to update all the animals hence why I added a field called lions

Comment: As already answered, use a dictionary, and not only during the update, as re-creating a dictionary for each update creates unnecessary overhead. Also add an `int` or `enum` (which is an int) Id property to your class, avoid strings as Ids, as these tend to be [less efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743474/key-performance-for-a-dictionary). This will make it easier to identify the class and very easy to look up in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

When working with list (which is a dynamic container) there is no way to find element without iterating over it.
One way you can make it more efficient is updating your `List` in one path and not using `LINQ` to find elements.
Something like this

```
foreach(vat animal in animalList) 
{
    if (animal.name == "Lion")
        animal.currentPopulation = ...
    else if (animal.name == "...")
        animal.currentPopulation = ...

}
```

I'd suggest you use different data container than list.
`Dictionary<string, Animal> animals` will serve you better because than you can use animal name as update keys.

Comment: Good point.. It looks like using a dictionary might be the better solution then.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void UpdatePopulations(Dictionary<string, int> populations)
{
    foreach(var population in populations)
        foreach(var animal in animalList.Where(x => x.name == population.Key))
            animal.currentPopulation = population.Value;        
}
```

**Usage:**

```
variableName.UpdatePopulations(new Dictionary<string, int> {
   ["Lion"] = 1000,
   ["Cat"] = 2000,
   ["Dog"] = 3000
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also differentiate with the help of 'enum' as shown below but you need to iterate through list to identify animal.

```
public enum AnimalName
{
    Lion,
    Cat,
    Dog
}

public class Animal
{
    public AnimalName Name { get; set; }

    public int Population { get; set; }

    public Animal(AnimalName name, int population)
    {
        Name = name;
        Population = population;
    }
}

public void UpdatePopulations(int lionPopulation, int catPopulation, int dogPopulation)
    {
        foreach (var animal in animals)
        {
            switch (animal.Name)
            {
                case AnimalName.Lion:

                    animal.Population = lionPopulation;
                    break;

                case AnimalName.Cat:

                    animal.Population = catPopulation;
                    break;

                case AnimalName.Dog:

                    animal.Population = dogPopulation;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is almost no benefit to convert the animalList to Dictionary, if you are going to update all of the animals anyway. Some improvement that I can think of is to accept IEnumerable instead, so you can freely update certain or all animals.

```
public void UpdatePopulations(IEnumerable<Animal> newAnimals)
{
    var dictionary = newAnimals.ToDictionary<string, int>(a=>a.Name, a=>a.currentPopulation); // convert to dictionary, so that we have O(1) lookup during the search later. This process itself is O(n)
    foreach(var animal in animalList) // this will be O(n)
    {
        if(dictionary.ContainsKey(animal.Name))
        {
            animal.currentPopulation = dictionary[animal.Name].currentPopulation;
        }
    }
}
```